# With Mercurial, if there are two local clones, can you push from one branch to another branch?

Tags: mercurial

If there are two branches, and I have been doing work on the `default` branch, I think one way to push to the `foo` branch of the other clone is

```
cd ~/development/clone2
hg up default
hg pull ~/developmet/clone1
hg up foo
hg merge default
```

or

```
cd ~/development/clone1
hg up default
hg push ~/developmet/clone2
cd ~/development/clone2
hg up foo
hg merge default
```

These 2 methods work exactly the same? (one is a pull, one is a push).

Is there an easier way to directly push clone1's `default` branch to clone2's `foo` branch?  thanks.

(I use clone 1 to see all the changes I have done (without seeing anybody else's changes), and use clone2 to merge and integrate with other team members)

Answer (score 0):

You can always push and pull a single revision and all of it ancestors using:

```
hg push -r revision ~/development/clone1
```

or

```
hg pull -r revision ~/development/clone2
```

Comment: but what about the branches... from branch1 to branch2

Comment: push and pull will never change the branch on which a changeset exists, nothing will.  Branch is an immutable part of a changeset in mercurial.  You can get the contents/effects of that change from one branch to another using 'merge', which creates new changesets.  There's a great overview and comparison of clone-branching vs. named-branch-branching vs. bookmark-branching at http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to "push to another branch" because you'll always have to merge the two different branches manually

Both methods you described work exactly the same, but the first one is recommended (Always do the merge work in your clone, not the integration repository or somebody else's clone)

Maybe is an intentional omission but in both examples you have to commit the result of the merge and in the first example you have to push the merge changeset back to clone2

So in ~/development/clone1 do:

```
hg up default
hg pull -u ~/development/clone2
hg up foo
hg merge default 
hg ci -m 'merged default into foo'
hg push ~/development/clone2
```

If you do this a lot you may consider adding this lines to your ~/development/clone1/.hg/hgrc file

```
[paths]
default = ~/development/clone2
```

This way you can omit the repository path when you're pulling and pushing from the integration repository